# Hi any Jenkins Groovy expert here can calrify what does left shift operator << mean

Tags: jenkins, groovy, devops, jenkins-groovy, cicd

Hi any Jenkins Groovy expert here can calrify what does left shift operator mean in this sentence

[sb_mail_Filename << props.LinkVarVariant << '_#' << env.BUILD_NUMBER << '*cp*' << CPNUM_PARAM << '.log']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in groovy `a << b` corresponds to `a.leftShift(b)` method call.

so, it depends on type of `a` - in your case type of `sb_mail_Filename`.

for example if `sb_mail_Filename` is a StringBuilder then here is  description of leftShift for it: https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#leftShift(java.lang.Object)